# Excel Filter function on whole column as criteria

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I've got some issue with the filter function. When I'm using weeknum in a filter fuction on a whole column I get a Value Error. I guess I could solve it with the aggr. function but I can't get the correct solution.
The first formula does work.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few functions in **`Excel`** which don't spill an array when referencing a range. However, it does work, when applied to an array, therefore change the range into an array.

The trick is to add a plus sign `+` or double unary `--` before the ranges. Also, it would be better to convert the range into a `Structured References` aka `Tables` instead of taking the whole ranges, without unnecessarily iterating over the blank rows which does slows down the `Excel` Engine/Functionality and performances.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=FILTER(Table1,(WEEKNUM(+Table1[Date])=48)*(Table1[Cat2]="a"))
```

---

And as far I know these `91` Excel Functions, needs the `+` or `--` sign in front of the ranges.

[image]

---